# Can you attempt to rescue someone if you're outgunned?

Tags: halacha, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

Principle : Yehareg velo yaavor for murder - you can't kill a person to save your life.

Reason : We don't know whose life is more important ('whose blood is redder').

Implication: You can't kill yourself (suicide) even to save someone else's life (since you don't know whose life is more important, yours or the other guy's).

---

Scenario : It's you vs 10 armed men who are holding your friend at gunpoint.

Question : Are you allowed to try to rescue your friend, even if you know it's virtual suicide in this situation?

- Seems like that'd be killing yourself to save someone else, which we said is not allowed.

Comment: To qualify your implication: You can’t actively kill yourself, but you can hand yourself over to be killed to save someone else. Not sure if that changes anything in this scenario.

Comment: What does "actively" mean? You see someone about to be hit by a car, the only way to save him is to push him out of the car's way, but then you know you'll get hit by it. Presumably that would clearly classify as "active". And it's pretty similar to the action in the question's scenario.

Comment: That’s what I’m unsure of, which is why I’m not posting an answer.

Comment: You talking about guns. War might have different rules.

Comment: To clarify, the principles in question here are וְנִשְׁמַרְתֶּם מְאֹד לְנַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם and וְאַ֨ךְ אֶת־דִּמְכֶ֤ם לְנַפְשֹֽׁתֵיכֶם֙ אֶדְר֔שׁ. _Yehareg ve'al ya'avor_ literally means "be killed rather than transgress" which is a different principle that doesn't apply here. That refers to transgressions that are so serious that one should not do them even to save his life. The stated reason ("We don't know whose life is more important") doesn't make sense with respect to every transgressions in that category.

Comment: "We don't set aside one person's life for another's" comes from a Mishna ([Ohalos 7:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Oholot.7?lang=bi))

Comment: Your "implication" does not follow logically from the two premises - "whose blood is redder" means you have no right to decide about others that they should be killed, but does not necessarily mean you may not endanger yourself if you choose to.

Comment: @Daniel: Right, the reason only applies to the "murder" one of the 3 yeharog ve'al ya'avor. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @simyou : Why do you say that? Is the would-be rescuer not a person too? As such, he can't decide between his person's worth and the other person's worth.

Comment: @user9806 there are decisions we can make regarding ourselves which we have no right to make when they concern others. Deciding to risk one's own life is very different than deciding to forfeit someone else's life because it seems fair to us. I am only saying that your third point ("Implication") does not necessarily follow from the first two, I am not saying it is wrong and not trying to answer your question.